# require in functions.php in local wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, require

I'm working on a wordpress theme locally using MAMP on Mac. It seems to be giving me a 500 error no matter what line I try. I'm trying to require the `/inc/customizer.php` in the `functions.php` file. This is a wordpress theme I'm building from scratch.

Here's what I tried:

```
require get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/inc/customizer.php';
```

.

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';
```

.

```
require get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/customzier.php';
```

Each of these either gives me a 500 error or a blank page. What is wrong?

Comment: What is in your PHP error log?

Comment: 1) there could be a syntax error on customizer.php 2) Child themes use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_template_directory ()` is not available yet if used outside any hook/function.

If it's outside any function, it should be:

```
<?php
/**
 * Theme functions and definitions
 */
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/customizer.php';
```

It would work if used like this:

```
add_action('wp_head', function(){
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';
});
```

Comment: I don't believe that's the case -- the docs for the function say it's available since version 1.5.0 https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

Comment: I didn't mean that. Added example.

Comment: Oh... duh :) Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The require might be having issues navigating to a URL path on your file system, rather than a relative path. Sometimes server settings don't allow for requires by URL / URI.

If you're developing a theme and `require`ing other files from the theme, wouldn't it make more sense to require based on a relative path? So if you're in index.php, you would just `require 'inc/customizer.php'`